# How to close an HTML tag that was created using document.createElement?

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, quill

I'm using QuillJS text editor which uses `document.createElement` to create things like `<p>`, `<br>` and `<img>`. However, I need these to be closed because I need them to be in XHTML format. Is it possible to use JS to self-close the elements that do not require a closing tag?

It doesn't matter if it is done on the client side or server side. If it can be done through PHP, NodeJS or client-side JS, I'd like to know how.

Comment: Tags are a feature of HTML/XHTML, they don't exist in the DOM, which is just a tree of elements.

Comment: So the issue is with the method you're using to turn the DOM into text. How are you doing that? You probably need to use some other method to create XHTML instead of HTML.

Comment: I'm not sure how that is done. It's done behind the scenes with QuillJS.

Comment: I don't know Quill, but check its preferences to see if there's  a way to distinguish between HTML and XHTML files. Maybe just changing the filename extension to `.xhtml` will trigger it to do the appropriate thing.

Comment: Quill is a client-side editor so it doesn't mess with files. It converts it into html text which you can handle as a string in JS.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your point. Quill properly closes tags it opens. Where/How do you see that?